# why XElement cannot save my xml file to the file?

Tags: c#, xml, save

I want to construct a long xml string and some of its entities are from another xml file read by a dll. In the end, I'd like to save this xml string to a file by `XElement.Save()`. It cannot save the string to the file.

For example:

```
XElement root = new XElement("Root");
// .....
root.Save(filename); // <-- wrong!
```

However, If I do not use the dll, everything is fine. Even I just call the dll and do nothing else, it won't work for me. Can anybody help me? Thanks

Comment: What actually *happens*? "It cannot save the string to the file" isn't a good description of the problem, nor does "wrong" in the code give us any information.

Comment: It works all fine but not saving the string as instructed. There is no error messages or other stuff I can check. As long as I touch the dll in the program, I cannot save the string.

Comment: Is the filename a relative one, or absolute? Is it a file which may have been used elsewhere in the program? Do you have any exception handling which could be hiding errors?

Comment: When I just save my own xml string and don't call the dll, it works fine.

Comment: [sorry the editor doesn't let me to enter the "enter" key for new line] ..... And when I call the dll and try to save my own xml string, it doesn't save. I guess there is something wrong in my program or the dll, but I could not find it out.

Comment: You still haven't answered my other questions. It's possible that code in the DLL is changing your process's working directory, which would affect what relative filenames mean. At the moment we simply haven't got enough information to help you...

Answer (score 2):

For Appending Node into existing XML File:
From beginning,

1) Create one `Root.xml file`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Main>
</Main>
```

2) Use this code to `Load and Append` Nodes:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Root");

XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Root.xml");
xdoc.Element("Main").Nodes().Last().AddAfterSelf(xml);  //append after the last backup element
xdoc.Save("Root.xml");
```

Comment: I think it may not be related to the xml formats.The xml string is composed of 2 parts: one from my program and the other from the dll. It doesn't save the string even I try just to save my own xml string. It's very strange.